# Insert libreoffice table as input

Tags: tables, luatex, input, open-office

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`odsfile`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/odsfile)

Suppose you have an `localc` spreadsheet `myspread.ods` and you want to insert the content of the range `H4:I40` as a table into your latex document. I know that I can export the table or just do some copy and paste. However is it possible to write something like:

`\includespread{file=myspread.ods,range=H4:I40}`

Then the table in my `LaTeX`-document changes when the corresponding spreadsheet changes.

Would be nice to have also the possibility to modify global appearence properties of the table as optional arguments of `\includespread`.

Comment: This isn't really possible in (PDF)LaTeX: `.ods` files are actually zip archives. Maybe with LuaTeX, which has a zip library, but then you need also to interpret the XML files contained in the archive.

Comment: too bad LuaTeX doen't have an XML library included :(

Answer (score 50, accepted):

---

Edit:
There is now LaTeX package for testing https://github.com/michal-h21/odsfile

Before I post it on CTAN, any comments on style/grammar/spell in the documentation files, as well comments on the source code, are highly welcome.

---

There is solution using luatex's `zip` library and pure lua xml processing library [LuaXML](http://manoelcampos.com/files/LuaXML-0.0.0-lua5.1.tgz), which you should install to same directory as `odsfile.lua`.

`ods` format consist of number of `xml` files packed in the `zip` file. data are contained in  `content.xml` file. its structure is following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" ... >
  <office:scripts/>
  <office:font-face-decls>
    ...
  </office:font-face-decls>
  <office:automatic-styles>
    ...
  </office:automatic-styles>
  <office:body>
    <office:spreadsheet>
      <table:table table:name="List1" table:style-name="ta1" table:print="false">
        <table:table-column table:style-name="co1" table:number-columns-repeated="3" table:default-cell-style-name="Default"/>
        <table:table-row table:style-name="ro1">
          <table:table-cell office:value-type="string">
            <text:p>Hello</text:p>
          </table:table-cell>
          <table:table-cell office:value-type="float" office:value="1">
            <text:p>1</text:p>
          </table:table-cell>
          <table:table-cell table:formula="of:=[.B1]+2" office:value-type="float" office:value="3">
            <text:p>3</text:p>
          </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
        ...
      </table:table>
      <table:table table:name="List2" table:style-name="ta1" table:print="false">
        ...
      </table:table>
    </office:spreadsheet>
  </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

From sample file I created, it seems that sheet data are saved in `office:document-content / office:body / office:spreadsheet / table:table` path. Table rows are saved as `table:table-row`  and cells as `table:table-cell`. Each cell has set datatype of its content, if cell contains formula it is saved in `table:formula` attribute. In every case, computed value ready for print is contained in subelement of `table-cell`, `text:p`. I hope this structure is created also with different versions of `Open/Libre Office Calc` than is mine, otherwise the code will be not working :(

With `LuaXML`, we can convert `xml` into `lua` tables, which can be then easily processed using standard `lua` techniques.

library `odsfile.lua`

```lua
module(...,package.seeall)
require "zip"
dofile("xml.lua")
dofile("handler.lua")


function load(filename)
  local p = {
    file = zip.open(filename),
    content_file_name = "content.xml",
    loadContent = function(self,filename)
      local treehandler = simpleTreeHandler()
      local filename = filename or self.content_file_name  
      local xmlfile = self.file:open(filename)
      local text = xmlfile:read("*a")
      local xml = xmlParser(treehandler)
      xml:parse(text)
      return treehandler
    end
  }
  return p
end

function getTable(x,table_name)
  local tables = x.root["office:document-content"]["office:body"]["office:spreadsheet"]["table:table"]
  if type(tables) == "table" and table_name ~= nil then 
    for k,v in pairs(tables) do
      if(v["_attr"]["table:name"]==table_name) then
        return v
      end 
    end
  elseif type(tables) == "table" and table_name == nil then
    return tables[1]  
  else 
    return tables  
  end
end

function tableValues(tbl,x1,y1,x2,y2)
  local t= {}
  if type(tbl["table:table-row"])=="table" then
    local rows = table_slice(tbl["table:table-row"],y1,y2)
    for k,v in pairs(rows) do
      local j = {}
      if #v["table:table-cell"] > 1 then
        local r = table_slice(v["table:table-cell"],x1,x2)
        for p,n in pairs(r) do
          table.insert(j,{value=n["text:p"],attr=n["_attr"]})
        end
      else
        local p = {value=v["table:table-cell"]["text:p"],attr=v["table:table-cell"]["_attr"]} 
        table.insert(j,p) 
      end  
      table.insert(t,j)
    end
  end
  return t
end

function getRange(range)
  local r = range:lower()
  local function getNumber(s)
    if s == "" or s == nil then return nil end
    local f,ex = 0,0
    for i in string.gmatch(s:reverse(),"(.)") do
      f = f + (i:byte()-96) * 26 ^ ex
      ex = ex + 1 
    end
    return f
  end
  for x1,y1,x2,y2 in r:gmatch("(%a*)(%d*):*(%a*)(%d*)") do
    return getNumber(x1),tonumber(y1),getNumber(x2),tonumber(y2) 
   --print(string.format("%s, %s, %s, %s",getNumber(x1),y1,getNumber(x2),y2))
  end
end

function table_slice (values,i1,i2)
  -- Function from http://snippets.luacode.org/snippets/Table_Slice_116
  local res = {}
  local n = #values
  -- default values for range
  i1 = i1 or 1
  i2 = i2 or n
  if i2 < 0 then
    i2 = n + i2 + 1
  elseif i2 > n then
    i2 = n
  end
  if i1 < 1 or i1 > n then
    return {}
  end
  local k = 1
  for i = i1,i2 do
    res[k] = values[i]
    k = k + 1
  end
  return res
end
```

Function `odsfile.load(filename)` returns `odsfile` object, with `loadContent()` method, which returns `lua` table representing `content.xml` file. We can select sheet from spreadsheet with `odsfile.getTable(xmlobject,sheet_name)`. If we omit `sheet_name`, first sheet from spreadsheet is selected.

Data from sheet can be read with `odsfile.tableValues(sheet, x1, y1, x2, y2)`. `x1 - y2` are range to be selected, they can be null, in which case whole rows and cells are selected. For converting of standard range expressions of form `a1:b2` to this representation, function `odsfile.getRange(range)` can be used.

Now some `LaTeX` interface. `odsfile.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{odsfile.sty}
\RequirePackage{luacode,xkeyval}

%keyval keys

\define@key{includespread}{file}{\loadodsfile{#1}}
\define@key{includespread}{sheet}{\luaexec{sheetname = "\luatexluaescapestring{#1}"}}
\define@key{includespread}{range}{\luaexec{%
local x1,y1,x2,y2 = odsreader.getRange("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}")%
range = {x1,y1,x2,y2}%
}}


\begin{luacode*}
odsreader = require("odsfile")
odsfile   = nil
sheetname     = nil
range     = {nil,nil,nil,nil}
\end{luacode*}

\newcommand\loadodsfile[2][]{%
  \setkeys{includespread}{#1}%
  \luaexec{%
    odsfile     = "\luatexluaescapestring{#2}"%
    local ods   = odsreader.load(odsfile)%
    odsfile, e  = ods:loadContent()%
  }%
}

\newcommand\includespread[1]{%
  \luaexec{range = {nil,nil,nil,nil}}%
  \setkeys{includespread}{#1}%
  \luaexec{%
    local body = odsreader.getTable(odsfile,sheetname)
    local values =odsreader.tableValues(body,range[1],range[2],range[3],range[4])
    local rowValues = function(row)
      local t={} 
      for _,column in pairs(row) do table.insert(t,column.value) end
      return t
    end   
    for i,row in pairs(values) do
      tex.sprint(table.concat(rowValues(row)," & ").."\\\\")
    end
  }
}
\endinput
```

In this version, you have to specify table columns manually, but it shouldn't be difficult to analyse for example contents of first row and generate column specification from this.

Example usage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{odsfile,lmodern}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

Inserting range from sheet

\begin{tabular}{l l}
\includespread{file=pokus.ods,sheet=List1,range=a2:b4}
\end{tabular}

Including of whole sheet

\begin{tabular}{l l l}
\includespread{}
\end{tabular}

Inserting second sheet

\begin{tabular}{l}
\includespread{file=pokus.ods,sheet=List2}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! `:)`

Comment: @michal.h21 I just tried in vain, I can not give you instead of one point, let's say, 20. But your answer is really an innovation.

Comment: @KeksDose thank you :) although  LuaXML is simple library with some bugs, it is sufficient in many cases

Comment: @PauloCereda  :)

Comment: @michal.h21 Impressing!

Comment: Thanks, that's amazing!! Perhaps the starting point of a new great LaTeX-package!

Comment: I concur with the bounty offerer: I don't need this, but what a great answer!

Comment: This (odsfile) is really a wonderful add-on for LaTeX, tables are a really messy issue. The latest version of LuaLaTeX has some incompatibility. The l`uaxml-mod-handler.lua` file use the deprecated `table.getn` function, all instances of this need to be replaced with `#`, e.g., `table.getn(self.stack)` should be replaced with `#self.stack`. However, there is still an issue with large tables with multiline cells, the multiline features in tabular do not seem to work, e.g., `\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}ll}` provide single line output only. This feature should really complete odsfile.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this by passing out a pipe of commands via \write18 to unzip the document.xml to stdin and into lxprintf (part of the LTxml suite from 
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/software/ltxml/ which lets you extract content from XML) and then munge the result via awk or whatever.  Or just use Perl/Tcl/Python.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Could you provide some more details?