# Create a LibreOffice spreadsheet from luatex

Tags: luatex, automation, open-office

After reading [this amazing answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/64006/8425), I'm wondering if it possible to do the same thing but the other way round, that is create a LibreOffice spreadsheet from luatex, exporting data from the `tex` file to the spreadsheet.

The example I have in mind is: say I'm typesetting the solution of an exam with a documentclass that defines a macro `\answer` to be used in the following context.

```
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}

\section{Test 1}

\begin{enumerate}
\item The \answer{definition of entropy} states that \answer{$S = k_B
    \ln \Omega$}. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I grade my students with a LibreOffice spreadsheet. So I'd like `luatex` to create (or modify) a spreasheet so I can have automatically something like in the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

I understand that [a lua interface to LibreOffice does not exist](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2009-04/msg00284.html). So I see three ways here:

1. Creating a zip file from scratch meeting the `.ods` standard.
2. Using some magic to interface LibreOffice API with luatex (with [LuaJava](http://www.keplerproject.org/luajava/index.html)?).
3. Using some perl or other kind of magic to do the job.

As @canaaerus suggested in comments, I could export things from `tex` with a csv file but I'd like to have a real `.ods` out of the box so that I could have style information (like bold face, centered text, etc.) and formulas.

Comment: Maybe you could use a `csv` files as data source for both your `TeX` document and your spreadsheet. The `datatool` package could help.

Comment: @canaaerus Well I was hoping to embed style information and possibly formulas. So csv is an idea but that will not fit fully my needs.

Comment: On second thought, you could also write to a `csv` file from `TeX` and then open it with `libreoffice`.

Comment: @canaaerus Yes, that was how I understood your first comment and it is indeed better than what I'm doing now (retyping all the answers in the spreadsheet...). But it is still not enough to store style information (bold, centered, etc.) or formulas.

Comment: Ok. But then you should maybe update your example.

Comment: The experimental Latex 3 data tables package [`l3dt`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3dt) will go a long way toward providing a data structure the Lua code can use as input.

Comment: What I meant with my comment above is, that your example does not show how you want the style information and formulas to be handled.

Comment: `lua` zip library is unfortunately only for reading `zip` files. but one can use zip utility to modify contents of archive. My idea is to use some `ods` file as template, where you can fill some columns with sample data and apply styles, then load this file with odsfile to lua table, use these template columns to insert new ones with style attributes copied. Then this lua table can be serialized back to the xml, template ods file copied to the new one and then replace `content.xml` in new `ods` file with our serialized table.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit 14-08-2012**
New version of `odsfile` incorporates ideas from this answer. It is now possible to use following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,odsfile,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\loadodsfile{template.ods}

\begin{AddRow}
\AddString{Hello world}{}
\AddNumber{46}{3}
\end{AddRow}

\includespread[template=booktabs,columns=head]
\savespreadsheet
\end{document}
```

Package is now included in `TeX Live` and `xml` library is distributed separately http://ctan.org/pkg/luaxml, so now it can be used by other packages.

---

This is my solution using `lualatex` and development version of [odsfile](https://github.com/michal-h21/odsfile). 
First of all, I created serialization function from `LuaXML` tables to `xml`.

Code

```lua
xml = require("xml-mod")
local t = {html={head = {title = "Hello world"}}} -- Table in format as created with LuaXML parser
print(xml.serialize(t))
```

outputs

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello world</title>
  </head>
</html>
```

Then there is small library for adding contents to ods file, `exams.lua`

```lua
module(...,package.seeall)
require("odsfile")
xml = require("xml-mod")


function updateZip(zipfile, updatefile)
  local command  =  string.format("zip %s %s",zipfile, updatefile)
  print ("Updating an ods file.\n" ..command .."\n Return code: ", os.execute(command))  
end

-- Object for adding new rows 

function newRow()
  local p = {
    pos = 0,
    cells = {},
    -- Generic function for inserting cell
    addCell = function(self,val, attr,pos)
      if pos then
        table.insert(self.cells,pos,{["text:p"] = val, ["_attr"] = attr})
        self.pos = pos
      else
        self.pos = self.pos + 1
        table.insert(self.cells,self.pos,{["text:p"] = val, ["_attr"] = attr})
      end
    end, 
    addString = function(self,s,attr,pos)
      local attr = attr or {}
      attr["office:value-type"] = "string"
      self:addCell(s,attr,pos)
    end,
    addFloat = function(self,i,attr,pos)
      local attr = attr or {}
      local s = tonumber(i) or 0
      s = tostring(s)
      attr["office:value-type"] = "float"
      attr["office:value"] = s
      self:addCell(s,attr,pos)
    end, 
    findLastRow = function(self,sheet)
      for i= #sheet["table:table-row"],1,-1 do
        if sheet["table:table-row"][i]["_attr"]["table:number-rows-repeated"] then
          return i
        end
      end
    end,
    insert = function(self, sheet, pos)
      local t = {}
      local pos = pos or self:findLastRow(sheet)
      for i=1, #sheet["table:table-column"] do
        table.insert(t,self.cells[i] or {})  
      end
      t = {["table:table-cell"]=t}
      table.insert(sheet["table:table-row"],pos,t)
    end
  }
  return p
end
```

It has one function and one object. `updateZip(zipfile, updatefile)` tries to run zip utility, which have to be installed in your system. Unfortunately, I have some problems with access rights on my computer, so it doesn't work here. Instead, I just run this command from commandline using generated `xml` and it works just fine.

newRow() returns object with some methods:

- `addCell(val,attr,pos)`
- `addString(val,attr,pos)`
- `addNumber(val,attr,pos)`
  these methods add columns into row. `addCell` is generic one and should not be used. attr is array with attributes, you can leave it empty. `pos` means position of the column in the row, it can also be `nil`
- `insert(sheet, pos)` 
  this function insert row to the sheet, you can specify row position with `pos`

Now some simple `LaTeX` package, `exams.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{exams}
\RequirePackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
exams = require("exams")
require("odsfile")
xml = require("xml-mod")
--exams.test()
row      = {}
sheet    = {}
ods      = {}
filename = ""
\end{luacode}

\newcommand\examspreadsheet[2]{%
 \luaexec{%
  sh = "\luatexluaescapestring{#2}"
  if sh == "" then sh = nil end
  filename = "\luatexluaescapestring{#1}"
  local f   = odsfile.load(filename)
  ods = f:loadContent()
  sheet = odsfile.getTable(ods,sh)
 }
}

\newcommand\savespreadsheet{%
\luaexec{exams.updateZip(filename,"content.xml")}
}
\newcommand\answer[1]{%
\begingroup%
\AddRow%
\AddNumber{\theenumi}{}%
\AddString{#1}{}%
\endAddRow%
\endgroup%
#1%
}
\newenvironment{exam}[1]{%
\section{#1}
\AddRow
\AddString{#1}{}
\endAddRow
\enumerate%
}{\endenumerate%
 \luaexec{%
   f = io.open("content.xml","w")
   f:write(xml.serialize(ods.root))
 }
}

\newenvironment{AddRow}[1][]{%
\def\AddString##1##2{% 
\luaexec{%
local pos = "\luatexluaescapestring{##2}"%
if pos == "" then pos = nil end; row:addString("\luatexluaescapestring{\unexpanded{##1}}",nil,pos)%
}%
}%
\def\AddNumber##1##2{%
\luaexec{%
local pos = "\luatexluaescapestring{##2}"%
if pos == "" then pos = nil end; row:addFloat("\luatexluaescapestring{##1}",nil,pos)%
}%
}%
\luaexec{%
pos = "\luatexluaescapestring{#1}"%
if pos == "" then pos = nil end; row = exams.newRow()%
}
}{%
\luaexec{%
row:insert(sheet,pos)%
}
}
```

This package defines three user commands and one environment:

- `\examspreadsheet{odsfile}{sheet}` loads sheet from file. you can left `sheet` blank, then first sheet will be selected
- `\answer{text}` add row to the spreadsheet
- `\savespreadsheet` saves sheet to the `ods file`
- environment `exam` all answers should be inside it, at end, it saves file `content.xml` in the current directory.

Note: there is some spurious space in definition of `\answer`, that I cannot find.

Now some sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,exams}
\begin{document}
\examspreadsheet{template.ods}{}

\begin{exam}{Test1}
\item Bla bla \answer{Test of special characters < > \& "}
\item The \answer{definition of entropy} states that \answer{$S = k_B
    \ln \Omega$}. 
\end{exam}
\savespreadsheet
\end{document}
```

Compile with

```
lualatex --shell-escape  sample.tex
```

If you get error message in the console output like:

```
zip I/O error: Permission denied

zip error: Could not create output file (was replacing the original zip file)
Updating an ods file.
zip template.ods content.xml
 Return code:   15
```

then you have to change file permissions of the `ods` file to enable writing for other users, or simply run command

```
zip -r template.ods content.xml
```

And the result in `openoffice calc`:

[image]

Comment: Hum, very promising indeed! Need to test it on real cases. Thanks :-)

Comment: Many thanks. This is indeed what I needed. This has to be rewarded :-)

Comment: @cjorssen thank you! note that current version of odsfile (not on ctan yet) has built-in support for adding rows and writing files tahnks to your question

Answer (score 10):

This is a long comment rather than an answer.

In ConTeXt you can generate XML corresponding to the document structure. For example, the ConTeXt document corresponding to your LaTeX example is:

```
\setupbackend[export=yes]
\definehighlight[answer] %[style=..., color=...]

\starttext
\startsection[title={Test 1}]
  \startitemize[n]
    \item The \answer{definition of entropy} states that \answer{$S=k_B ≤ Ω$}
  \stopitemize
\stopsection
\stoptext
```

The important part here is the `\setupbackend` command on the top. I do not know how you want to visually display the output of the `\answer` macro, so I left it blank.

Compiling this file generates the following `\jobname.export` file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?>

<!-- input filename   : test              -->
<!-- processing date  : Thu Jul 26 14:21:19 2012 -->
<!-- context version  : 2012.07.19 17:52  -->
<!-- exporter version : 0.30              -->


<document language="en" file="test" date="Thu Jul 26 14:21:19 2012" context="2012.07.19 17:52" version="0.30" xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <section detail="section" location='aut:1'>
    <sectionnumber>1</sectionnumber> 
    <sectiontitle>Test 1</sectiontitle> 
    <sectioncontent>
      <itemgroup detail="itemize" symbol="n">
        <item>
          <itemtag>1.</itemtag>
          <itemcontent>The <highlight detail="answer">definition of entropy</highlight> states that <highlight detail="answer"><m:math display="inline"><m:mrow><m:mi></m:mi><m:mo>=</m:mo><m:msub><m:mi></m:mi><m:mi></m:mi></m:msub><m:mo>≤</m:mo><m:mi>Ω</m:mi></m:mrow></m:math></highlight></itemcontent>
        </item>
      </itemgroup>
    </sectioncontent>
  </section>
</document>
```

This is a well formed XML containing all the information in the original document (including the `\answer` macro and the inline math snippet). In principle, it should be straightforward to take this XML and transform it to the format needed by Calc and zip it. (In fact, ConTeXt does something similar when generating epub output from TeX input). But I am know the XML processing tools well enough to give a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ConTeXt does once again a great job here, but I'm afraid I'll stick to LaTeX for some time more.

Comment: The other option is to start with an XML file. I believe there are LaTeX packages that can be used to process the XML file (ConTeXt can do this natively), otherwise you can use something from the XML toolchain to transform the input to both a valid latex and a valid ODS file.