# How can I convert structured LaTeX file *to* CSV data

Tags: datatool, forms, database

I am using a structured format to print patient's documenatation using LaTeX. The structure is like this:

**Demography**
Name Surname
Age/Sex
Address

**Clinical Details**
   History,  Past History, Personal History, Family History and others (as subsections) er:

**Examination**

**Diagnosis**
    Provisional
    Final

**Investigations**
    available and suggested

**Treatment**

I used koma article class (`scrartcl`) with `section`, `subsection`, `enumerate`. I am aware of the `datatool` package which I could have used to get the things done, while I would have documented the visit to csv/excel/calc. I could not figure out how a csv entries could be filtered so that I could print an individual patient record. 
My question is, if I follow above mentioned simple structure, is there any way to export the data of all patient to csv file/excel/calc for analysis?

I am typing the structure of `tex` file :

```
\documentclass[12pts]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}       % customizable list environments
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 
\@ifundefined{lettrine}{\usepackage{lettrine}}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.

\usepackage[us,24hr]{datetime}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\title{Consultation Report}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section*{Clinical details}

\subsection*{Present history}

\subsection*{Past History}

\subsection*{Personal history}

\subsection*{Family history }

\subsection*{Examination}
examination finding 
\section*{Diagnosis}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  Disease
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Rx}
\begin{enumerate}
\item here goes teatment
\item tab abc दिवसातून दोनदा 
\end{enumerate}
\begin{flushright}
My Name \\
{\footnotesize Qualification
}\\
{\footnotesize designation}\\
{\footnotesize Ph: }
\par\end{flushright}{\footnotesize \par}

\end{document}
```

---

I think I need to elaborate. Till date I was using the template provided to create a regular consultation. The receptionist used to create a folder named after the patient and insert a `demography.tex` file containing

```
Name surname \\\ dob\\\address\\\Phone.
```

I used to create small tex files named as `yymmdd.tex` where I used to enter clinical data. Clinical data included history, examination and diagnosis.
We use to create a third small file `Rx.tex` where itemised treatment used to go. The three files used to be compiled by placing `\input` commands in a template provided. The advantage of having three small files was I could use demography in a follow up visit. Treatment mostly had to be modified a little bit. The clinical data used to change, so I had to change the input file everytime in a template. Overall, the text generated used to have consistent patern. I could share the folders on intranet. But possibly there is better way of doing this using data tool. I had two problems using data tool.

1. Though I understood how to create tables using data tool, I failed to understand how an individual entry can be used. E.g. presenting history for presenting history in already provided template, past history at past history template.
2. If I use unique identification no for every patient and visit, how can I export only the data for the visit day to latex template.

If I can figure it out, then may be all my patient data can be entered on excel and exported to latex templates to create a needed document. The question, why not use a MySQL like database? It seems beyond my capacity and available time to learn new tool, though it may be worth it. In no way I am creating emr. That is way beyond. If you can help me out in getting cvs to LaTeX template I provided I will be obliged. For technical reason I would like `|` to be separator and not the comma.

Comment: To clarify, you have a bunch of identically structured documents and you want to scrape them for information. Are the documents `.tex`, `.pdf` or something else? Do you really want/need to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Are you restricted to using LaTeX for this? A script language would probably be a better fit.

Comment: .tex. I do not know Scripting language like xml. I use latex because 1. i know it a little bit. 2. i like the way documents are rendered. 3. i do not have to bother about formatting once i define the structure 4. i do not want a database program/ out of box program as it will limit my portability.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We need an example of how you structure your TeX file to be able to give some hints.

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file?

Comment: I have edited the question to include *tex* file

Comment: Other way round, how can i use datatool package to achieve same structure. That means I will be typing on calc/excel and saving as csv. If I use single excel file to include all my patients, I need to filter out patient by Id and by date, so that the data of only relevant patient is printed. Though this will be a prospective creation of database, I will be happy with that if there is nothing like latex to csv.

Comment: What do you want the resulting `.csv` file to look like (e.g., what information should go in it, how are blank sections handled?).

Comment: The csv file should contain section and subsection as the headers. The blank section will end up as "blank" field. If it is csv to latex, blank section should be deleted/not printed. vaibhav
PC: I am requesting you to help create a latex based electronic medical record system :)

Comment: This question needs quite a bit of clarification. For an electronic medical record system it does not make any sense to store the original data in LaTeX. LaTeX works nice to render the documents from a given datasource but the other way around is not a good idea, especially if you implement this from scratch. So maybe you can clarify about the requirements of your setup. As it stands now this has no real answer, as it is possible to write to a csv file from LaTeX but you do not want to go that route if it can be avoided.

Comment: The [answers here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64528/14100) might be useful.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the comments that you'd need a scripting language to extract the information from your existing documents, but once you have the information in a database you can use the datatool package to generate a report for a particular patient. For the type of information you want to save, I wouldn't recommend using csv as I would find that tricky to edit (but that depends on what you use to edit it). Here's how it might look in csv form (using | as a separator as you requested):

```
Patient Number|Name|Surname|DoB|Sex|Address|Phone|History|Past History|Personal History|Family History|Examination|Diagnosis|Treatment
0001|Joe|Bloggs|1974-12-06|Male|"1 The Street, The Town"|0123456|Joe's patient history here|Joe's past history here|Joe's personal history|Joe's family history|Joe's examination|\begin{enumerate}\item Joe's diagnosis\end{enumerate}|\begin{enumerate}\item Joe's treatment\end{enumerate}
0002|Jane|Doe|1970-05-18|Female|"2 The Street, The Town"|0123457|Mary's patient history here|Mary's past history here|Mary's personal history|Mary's family history|Mary's examination|\begin{enumerate}\item Mary's diagnosis\end{enumerate}|\begin{enumerate}\item Mary's treatment\end{enumerate}
0003|John|Smith|1969-01-20|Male|"3 The Street, The Town"|01234568|John's patient history here|John's past history here|John's personal history|John's family history|John's examination|\begin{enumerate}\item John's diagnosis\end{enumerate}|\begin{enumerate}\item John's treatment\end{enumerate}
```

Alternatively, the same information can be store in a .tex file using the datatool format:

```
\DTLnewdb{patients}
% Patient Joe Bloggs (patient number 0001)
\DTLnewrow*{patients}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Patient Number}{0001}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Name}{Joe}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Surname}{Bloggs}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{DoB}{1974-12-06}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Sex}{Male}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Address}{1 The Street, The Town}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Phone}{0123456}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{History}{Joe's patient history here}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Past History}{Joe's past history here}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Personal History}{Joe's personal history}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Family History}{Joe's family history}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Examination}{Joe's examination}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Diagnosis}
{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Joe's diagnosis
  \end{enumerate}
}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Treatment}
{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Joe's treatment
  \end{enumerate}
}
% Patient Jane Doe (patient number 0002)
\DTLnewrow*{patients}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Patient Number}{0002}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Name}{Jane}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Surname}{Doe}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{DoB}{1970-05-18}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Sex}{Female}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Address}{2 The Street, The Town}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Phone}{0123457}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{History}{Mary's patient history here}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Past History}{Mary's past history here}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Personal History}{Mary's personal history}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Family History}{Mary's family history}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Examination}{Mary's examination}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Diagnosis}
{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Mary's diagnosis
  \end{enumerate}
}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Treatment}
{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Mary's treatment
  \end{enumerate}
}
% Patient John Smith (patient number 0003)
\DTLnewrow*{patients}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Patient Number}{0003}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Name}{John}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Surname}{Smith}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{DoB}{1969-01-20}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Sex}{Male}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Address}{3 The Street, The Town}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Phone}{0123458}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{History}{John's patient history here}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Past History}{John's past history here}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Personal History}{John's personal history}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Family History}{John's family history}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Examination}{John's examination}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Diagnosis}
{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item John's diagnosis
  \end{enumerate}
}
\DTLnewdbentry*{patients}{Treatment}
{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item John's treatment
  \end{enumerate}
}
```

You can access a particular patient like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{datatool}

% load from csv file:
%\DTLsetseparator{|}
%\DTLloaddb{patients}{patients.csv}
% or load from .tex file:
\input{patients}

\title{Consultation Report}
\author{}

\newcommand*{\getdetails}[1]{%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\patientdetails}{\dtlcolumnindex{patients}{#1}}%
  \patientdetails
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% fetch patient's details (patient number 0002)
\dtlgetrowforvalue{patients}{\dtlcolumnindex{patients}{Patient Number}}{0002}%

\begin{tabular}{ll}
Name: & \getdetails{Name} \getdetails{Surname}\\
DoB: & \getdetails{DoB}\\
Sex: & \getdetails{Sex}\\
Address: & \getdetails{Address}\\
Phone: & \getdetails{Phone}
\end{tabular}

\section*{Clinical details}

\subsection*{Present history}

\getdetails{History}

\subsection*{Past History}

\getdetails{Past History}

\subsection*{Personal history}

\getdetails{Personal History}

\subsection*{Family history }

\getdetails{Family History}

\subsection*{Examination}

\getdetails{Examination}

\section*{Diagnosis}

\getdetails{Diagnosis}

\section*{Rx}

\getdetails{Treatment}

\begin{flushright}
My Name \\
{\footnotesize Qualification
}\\
{\footnotesize designation}\\
{\footnotesize Ph: }
\par\end{flushright}{\footnotesize \par}

\end{document}
```