# A program to export latex tables to excel/ods/csv?

Tags: tables, r, excel, export

I know there are tools to export excel tables to latex, but what about the other way around?  I get a lot of latex tables from functions in R (e.g.: texreg) that aren't perfectly customizable via the code, and need some editing.  For example, I'll have variables like T:X and X:T as separate rows, based on how whatever model function interpreted an interaction expansion.  I'd like to be able to input a tabular object and get .csv-like table, which I could then edit and re-export (using calc2latex in my case).

Anything like this exist?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65079/2891

Comment: Copy and paste the contents, remove all the \\ and \hline and then import with using & as delimiters?

Answer (score 13):

Far from perfection, but for a document with a single table you can use `detex` and then replace `&` by `,` and delete empty lines. In Linux you can use some tools as `grep` and `sed` for this. The first line of the table is then the columns types, so you can delete manually or with some tool like `tail`. Example command line:

> ```
> detex file.tex | grep -v '^$' | tail -n+2  | sed 's/&/,/g' > file.csv
> ```

Example input `file.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
    11 & 12 & 13 & 14\\
    21 & 22 & 23 & 24\\
    31 & 32 & 33 & 34\\
    41 & 42 & 43 & 44\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Ouput (`file.csv`):

```
    11 , 12 , 13 , 14
    21 , 22 , 23 , 24
    31 , 32 , 33 , 34
    41 , 42 , 43 , 44
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another workaround, if you have Excel or a similar application, and you can manage to make a LaTeX file that contains only the table: convert the LaTeX file using pandoc to HTML, as follows:

`pandoc -o output.html input.tex`

Then, import the resulting HTML table into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you are an Emacs user, you can save this function in your init file.

```
(defun latex-table-export-to-csv-file (&optional file)
               "Creates a file  <base file name>-<start position>-<end position>.csv from the LaTeX table elements.
                The point must be within any LaTeX table & separated.
                The filename argument is for a programmatically call.
                This function only needs the point (cursor) in a LaTeX table.
             It creates a csv file <base file name>-<start position>-<end position>.csv.
             There is no check for point not in a LaTeX table but no error."
               (interactive )
    
               (let* ((end (save-excursion (search-forward "\\end" nil t)(beginning-of-line)(point)))
                      (beg(save-excursion (search-backward "\\begin" nil t)
                                          (re-search-forward "^.*&.*" nil t)
                                          (beginning-of-line)(point)))
                      (tbl (buffer-substring beg end)))
    
                 (unless file (setq file (format "%s-%d-%d.csv" (file-name-sans-extension buffer-file-name) beg end)))
    
                 (with-temp-buffer
                   (insert tbl)
                   (org-table-convert-region (point-min) (point-max) "&\\|\\\\\\\\.*")
                   (org-table-export file "orgtbl-to-csv" ))))
```

It only needs the point (cursor) to be in a LaTeX table.
It creates a csv file <base file name>-<start position>-<end position>.csv. there is no check for not in a LaTeX table but no error.

You can active this function with `M-x latex-table-export-to-csv-file` or you can define a key sequence to activate it. I chose `C-c t` but it's up to you to have an other choice.
Save this code in your init file:

```
(bind-key (kbd "C-c t") #'latex-table-export-to-csv-file LaTeX-mode-map)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep all the LaTeX in the table, you can get away with the following series of regular expressions. This example uses Vim's regexp, through the [vims](https://github.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream) script.

```bash
cat table.tex | vims \
    '1,/begin{tabular}/d' \
    '/end{tabular}/,$d' \
    '%g/^\s*$/d' \
    '%s/^\s*//g' \
    '%s/^/"/g' \
    '%s/\s*&\s*/","/g' \
    '%s/\\\\/"/g' \
    > output.tex
```

- `'1,/begin{tabular}/d'` Delete up to begin{tabular}
- `'/end{tabular}/,$d'` Delete after to end{tabular}
- `'%g/^\s*$/d'` Delete empty lines
- `'%s/^\s*//g'` Delete starting indentation
- `'%s/^/"/g'` Add " to the start
- `'%s/\s*&\s*/","/g'` Replace `&` (capturing nearby white space) with `","`
- `'%s/\\\\/"/g'` Replace the newline char with `"`